# enable cross domain requests in google chrome browser using Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is there any way to allow cross domain (CORS) requests in browser using angular2?
Because i am able to call this type of requests using **ionic2**. But i want to enable these type of requests only in angular2 applications.

i made an entry to enable proxies inside **ionic.config.json** in the following way,

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/token",
      "proxyUrl": "http://10.74.39.249:8881/app/rest/v1.0/service"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing an angular2 app with a c# web api backend, and I have also ran into issues where angular claims that there is a problem with my cors settings, when in reality it was the data that I send to the api at fault.

My suspicion is that when you make an http request through angular, it attempts to find the url you requested, and if it is unable to, it assumes that there is a problem with the cors settings since you and the api are on the same host.

In my case I was trying to send a js date object to the api which expected a c# datetime type, even though my url was set correctly, angular saw that it would be unable to pass the js date object into the c# datetime parameter and and assumed that this wasnt the endpoint that I wanted to hit.

After modifying the data that I wanted to send to comply with how the c# datetime type is structured, the api call worked. Try inspecting the request that angular makes with a tool like fiddler or google chrome to make sure that everything looks correct, because there is a good chance that angular is leading you on a wild goose chase.